# Search a text file for List of names in JAVA

Tags: java, list, search, full-text-search, directory

I have the following:

1. Folder that contains many files (about 300000), named "AllFilesFolder"
2. list of names, named "namesList"
3. An empty folder, named "filteredFolder"

I want to filter the folder "AllFilesFolder", by moving any file that contins any of the names in the list to the empty folder "filteredFolder".

I have approche this problem by the following code:

```
public static void doIt(List<String>namesList, String AllFilesFolder, String filteredFolder) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // here we put all the files in the original folder in List variable name "filesList"
    File[] filesList = new File(AllFilesFolder).listFiles();


    // went throught the files one by one 
    for (File f : filesList) {

        try {

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = "";
            //this varibale used to test withir the files contins names or not 
            //we set it to false.
            boolean goodDoc = false;
            //go through the file line by line to chick the names (I wounder if there are a simbler whay)
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                for(String name:namesList){
                if ( line.contains(name)) {
                    goodDoc = true;
                }
                }
            }
            reader.close();

            // if this file contains the name we put this file into the other folder "filteredFolder"
            if (goodDoc) {
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filteredFolder + f.getName()));
                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
                while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

By doing this I have two problems that I need your advice to solve:

1. I am reading each file twice, one time to search and the other to put it into the other folder.
2. When searching namesList I have for loop to takes the names one by one, Is there a way to search the list one time (without loop).

Many thanks in advance

Comment: When you set `goodDoc = true;` add a `break;`. This will stop you reading to the end of the file once you determine that the file has one of your words in it.

Comment: Good point thank you @OldCurmudgeon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am reading each file twice, one time to search and the other to put it into the other folder.**

Using NIO improves the copy performance. Here is the [code example.](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17036.html) If you can use Java 7 then you can use [Files.copy()](http://codingjunkie.net/java-7-copy-move/)

**When searching namesList I have for loop to takes the names one by one, Is there a way to search the list one time (without loop).**

Use `HashSet` to store the names and use `contains()` method. It is a **O(1)** operation. Or another suggestion is to use [Scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern, horizon)](http://www.coderanch.com/t/278043/Streams/java/Searching-large-text-file)

Comment: Thank you @Pangea. The `Files.copy()` did save time. However, `Scanner function` did not work with me. I'm grateful.